# Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager Console looks strange -- installed correctly?

Tags: symantec, endpoint, symantec-endpoint-protection

I have Symantec Endpoint Protection installed on a Windows Server 2003 box, and the management console looks strange. It looks like pieces are missing [0]. What's more is I can't generate reports, and the Monitors screen is largely blank.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

[0]
http://www.agocsdata.com/endpoint/SymantecEMC.PNG

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once before, and I believe it was a Java version issue.

Comment: Is this running on the same system that has the SEPM installed or from another system?

Comment: What version of SEP are you running MR4 or..?

Comment: This is running on the same system that has SEPM installed. And how do I check the version of SEP? Near as I can tell, it's SEPM 11.0.4.

Comment: Click on About and look for a version 11.0.4202.75  That is our version of SEPM.  As Chales mentioned, it sound like  a Java issue.  In Add/Remove programs, unistall any instyalled Jave and restsrt (if possible) and then open the SEPM again.  That should install the needed Java version.

Comment: I agree with the comments so far regarding the java version.  Have you tried connecting to the SEP Manager Console from the browser on your local workstation to see if you get the same results/view?  http://servername:9090